# Experience Manager with DD4T not working

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t

I am implementing experience manager on my DD4T website. I am using Albert solution to implement experience manager. Url whose steps I followed is http://albertromkes.com/category/dd4t/. Some how this solution not working. I can see page source rendering some tags required for siteedit but not javascript tag for siteedit .

I have used only few fields of component to implement(2 out of 5 fields) site edit. Please suggest if this may be a cause of issue. Also while browsing the page I can't see any log prepared in session preview service whose log is configured as verbose.

Thanks.
Mukesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To write out the bootstrapper.js (The JavaScript that 'renders' the 'SDL Tridion' button for XPM), use the following code (at the bottom of your page/shared View):

`@Html.SiteEditPage(Model)`. `Model` being an `IPage` object from DD4T.

And you don't have to make every field from your component editable :)

The fact that Session Preview doesn't seem to work is unrelated to this. Did you follow the steps as described in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539)? (Login required). If it's still not working, please post another question with the specifics.

Comment: Thanks Albert, I have followed all the steps except using Enable inline editing for Page, Enable inline editing for content in the CT.

Comment: So editing now works, but Session Preview doesn't?

Comment: Yes, it is showing me link to redirect to edit in CMS. But url is redirecting to blank white screen i.e. url is not correct. Can you please suggest what may be the root cause.

Comment: It was my mistake, it is working now. Now the problem is I can edit metadata of the page, but I can't update the content of component. Please suggest..

Comment: @Mukesh: Suggesting you to please raise a separate question for the new issue with all your findings